# Can we add user defined operator in java manually

Tags: java, jvm

I want to do something like this:
int a=4 plus 5;

Here `plus` is userdefined operator that is defined by me  may in jvm level. Is it possible to do something like that

Comment: Go learn Scala if you really want to do that

Comment: If you can’t distinguish between source code level and JVM level, you shouldn’t even think about that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to define infix operators or overload existing operator symbols in the Java language.

You can however use a language which suppots this, if it compiles to the JVM (bytecode).

It is one of the reasons why alternative JVM languages like JRuby, Groovy or Scala are used, especially if you want to form a internal DSL. They all have more freedoms in this area (to a varying degree).

And if you don't want to compile to Java you can also use the built-in script interpreter framework and use a more flexible scripting language supported. (for example you can extend Jasper Reports with Groovy).

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that Scala goes in that direction too